# Python Pandas: Drop ongoing values from column

Tags: python, pandas, preprocessor

following problem:
I have a big time series dataframe with total returns for a stock index. When a stock drops out of the index the value will be set constant until the last date in the dataframe. **I want to set the values to NaN as soon as they are constant (as soon as the drop out of the index).** How can I do that?

[drop the yellow marked values (all but the first)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYjL8.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You can take `diff` and replace the values with `np.nan`s where `diff` equals to 0 with `where` (note that it's kind of reversed, "take values from `df` if it's not equal to 0, otherwise `np.nan`):

```
df.where(df.diff().ne(0), np.nan)
```

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5],
    'y': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4],
})

df.where(df.diff().ne(0), np.nan)
```

Output:

```
     x    y
0  1.0  1.0
1  2.0  NaN
2  3.0  NaN
3  NaN  2.0
4  NaN  3.0
5  NaN  NaN
6  4.0  NaN
7  5.0  4.0
```

**Update** To only remove the values that are the same until the end of the series, we can find the interval to be replaced with `np.nan`s with `diff` and `cumsum`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    'y': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4],
})

df.where(
    df.diff().ne(0)[::-1].cumsum().ne(0)[::-1],
    np.nan)
```

Output:

```
     x  y
0  1.0  1
1  2.0  1
2  3.0  1
3  NaN  2
4  NaN  3
5  NaN  3
6  NaN  3
7  NaN  4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer! But I think I wasnt clear enough in my question sorry. I only want to delete values that drop out completely and until the end of the time series. So the problem with this solution is that it also deletes values that are (randomly) identical for one period (before the stock actually stays constant until the end) and therefor it deletes a lot of values that should not be deleted.

Comment: @MaxN Yes, sorry, that wasn't clear, let me update the answer...